# Bootstrap: How to stabilize the container padding while changing the window size?

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

When one change the size of the browser's window, I noticed that the padding between the window border and the row (in red) is changing as you can see here:

[image]

**Then, reducing the window:**

[image]

The code I used to make this simple example is:

```
 <!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <title>Bootstrap Example</title>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>



<div class="container">
<br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br>

  <div class="row" style="background-color: red;margin: 20px;">
  <br>
  </div>

</div>

</body>
</html>
```

So, I tried to change the class "container", like this:

```
<style>

.container {

  padding-right: auto;

  padding-left: auto;

  margin-right: 15px;

  margin-left: 15px;

}

</style>
```

This time, the padding on the left will no move when I change the browser's window, BUT the padding on the right is different and will change:

[image]

**Then reducing the window:**

[image]

Sorry for all those pictures, but an image is better than an explaination.

Thank you

Comment: You can't apply auto to padding. That only works for magrin.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the first thing you need to know it that `auto` is not a valid value for the `padding` property. Try using `margin: auto` for the container. I tried your code in this fiddle and it works fine;

https://jsfiddle.net/j7ezbvdq/2/

Comment: Just to note. They would just need to remove the margin left and right, because bootstrap already applies `margin-left: auto; margin-right: auto;` to `.container` classes.

Comment: I've updated the fiddle to a fixed margin, because it seems you want the margin to stay the same size when resizing the window.

https://jsfiddle.net/j7ezbvdq/2/

Answer (score 0):

Idea of the `.container` class is it centre the div with some fixed widths as define bellow.

```
@media (min-width: 1200px)
.container {
    width: 1170px;
}

@media (min-width: 992px)
.container {
    width: 970px;
}

@media (min-width: 768px)
.container {
    width: 750px;
}
```

Also it has properties like this

```
.container {
    padding-right: 15px;
    padding-left: 15px;
    margin-right: auto;
    margin-left: auto;
}
```

If you check with inspect elements it is not padding get reduced.  It is the margin.

**Also please note `auto` is not a valid property value for paddings.**

Answer (score 0):

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <title>Bootstrap Example</title>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

  <style>

.container {

  padding-right: auto;
  padding-left: auto;
  margin:auto;
}
.row
{
 
 margin:auto;
 border: 8px solid red;

}
</style>

</head>
<body>



<div class="container">
<br><br><br>

  <div class="row">
</div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Simple example for stable adjustment for all kinds of screen.

Comment: It does not work when I run this code on my own server

Comment: which server and finally you will run in browser only, right?